# Apache rewrite subnet ip range

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can someone please tell me how to put the following IP ranges (belongs to Cloudfront) in a mod_rewrite?
I am looking to redirect the non-www requests for example.com to www.example.com BUT not redirect any IP address coming from IP Ranges below:

```
54.192.0.0/16
54.230.0.0/16
54.239.128.0/18
54.239.192.0/19
54.240.128.0/18
204.246.164.0/22
204.246.168.0/22
204.246.174.0/23 
204.246.176.0/20 
205.251.192.0/19 
205.251.249.0/24 
205.251.250.0/23 
205.251.252.0/23 
205.251.254.0/24 
216.137.32.0/19
```

I used a tool called **rgxg** to convert all of the above from CIDR to Regex and created the following entries in my httpd.conf:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !54\.192(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]||1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){2} 

    RewriteRule ^/(.*)?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

I have added all the ip ranges in my RewriteCond entries but included only the first one as I didn't want to clutter this post.  The rule don't appear to work.  If I put just a single IP address, it works without a problem.

Can someone please check and see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
-Ma

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the first range:

```
54.192.0.0/16
```

In the regex

```
54\.192(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]||1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){2}
```

Notice the double `||`. Given how hard it is to debug, if there is even one mistake, I don't feel bad throwing the whole thing away.

The following is not quite `exact` because it would match fragments up to `999`, but all that matters is that it catches all IPs in the range, and no other valid IPs. It does.

```
54\.192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

And it's easy to read. I would recommend using that instead. Try it, and if that works, the other ones can also be revisited.

I am not sure how you receive the IP, but depending on context this is another option:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54\.192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

Let's look at some potential ranges:

```
54.192.0.0/16 => ^54\.192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
54.230.0.0/16 => ^54\.230\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$
54.239.128.0/18 => ^54\.239\.(?:19[01]|1[3-8][0-9]|12[89])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
54.239.192.0/19 => ^54\.239\.(?:22[0-3]|2[01][0-9]|19[2-9])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
54.240.128.0/18 => ^54\.240\.(?:19[01]|1[3-8][0-9]|12[89])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
204.246.164.0/22 => ^204\.246\.16[4-7]\.[0-9]{1,3}$
204.246.168.0/22 => ^204\.246\.(?:17[01]|16[89])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
204.246.174.0/23  => ^204\.246\.17[45]\.[0-9]{1,3}$
204.246.176.0/20 => ^204\.246\.(?:19[01]|18[0-9]|17[6-9])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
205.251.192.0/19 => ^205\.251\.(?:22[0-3]|2[01][0-9]|19[2-9])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
205.251.249.0/24 => ^205\.251\.249\.[0-9]{1,3}$
205.251.250.0/23 => ^205\.251\.25[01]\.[0-9]{1,3}$
205.251.252.0/23 => ^205\.251\.25[23]\.[0-9]{1,3}$
205.251.254.0/24 =>  ^205\.251\.254\.[0-9]{1,3}$
216.137.32.0/19 => ^216\.137\.(?:6[0-3]|[45][0-9]|3[2-9])\.[0-9]{1,3}$
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm a bit confused how to create the regex version of a CIDR.  Would the following be accurate for CIDR 54.239.128.0/18:   RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !=54\.239\.128\.[1-8]{1,3} ?

Comment: Thank you.  I can't get my head wrapped around how these regex's are produced.  This is helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. These were produced by a colleague who has cool tools but doesn't like to share them, although he likes to show off about what they can do. :)

Comment: I added all the regex in RewriteCond but for some reason coming from the ranges, mod_rewrite still redirects me to www.example.com.  I want to keep the call as example.com for these ranges.  Thoughts?

Comment: With a range specified by a regex and the `^` `$` anchors, we should use `!` directly, please try `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^54\.192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^54\.192\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$`

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Apache HTTPD 2.4 or later, you can also use [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html) to match REMOTE_ADDR against a CIDR mask directly, instead of converting these to regexps.

The short form looks like this:

```
RewriteCond expr "-R '192.168.1.0/24'"
```

The following longer form is also available, but the documentation suggests it is less efficient:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '192.168.1.0/24'"
```

Comment: One can negate the expression with `RewriteCond expr "! %{REMOTE_ADDR} -ipmatch '192.168.1.0/24'"`